# What is the difference between "vegetable garden" and "vegetable patch"?

Tags: difference

one of the meanings of "patch" from [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/patch):

> patch — a small area of land where a particular fruit or vegetable grows

one of the meanings of "garden" from [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/garden):

> garden — an area of ground where plants (such as flowers or vegetables) are grown

images of "vegetable patch" from [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vegetable%20patch%22&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjDm-TvgduBAxXs-SoKHewZBfoQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22vegetable%20patch%22&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQDFAAWABgAGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=aaEcZYPDMuzzqwHss5TQDw&bih=625&biw=1366&rlz=1C1CHBD_ruRU904RU904)
images of "vegetable garden" from [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vegetable%20garden%22&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjG6-zqgduBAxWXGxAIHbyfBAEQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22vegetable%20garden%22&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQDDIHCAAQigUQQzIHCAAQigUQQzIHCAAQigUQQzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgcIABCKBRBDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgcIABCKBRBDUABYAGCp_QFoAHAAeACAAXOIAeEBkgEDMC4ymAEAqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=X6EcZYbAHZe3wPAPvL-SCA&bih=625&biw=1366&rlz=1C1CHBD_ruRU904RU904)

The word "small" is only in the definition of "patch".
But proceeding from the images, "vegetable garden" and "vegetable patch" are the same in size.
So could you tell me please what the difference is between them?

Comment: You can't gauge the typical size from Google images. A 'vegetable patch' could be the section of a larger garden which is dedicated to vegetable growing (the rest of the garden containing flowers and often a lawn).

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything called a "vegetable garden" could also be called a "vegetable patch".

When I compare the two in my head, the garden feels more like the central focus of the area, while the patch feels like some random part of a larger area like a yard, field or farmland. I would guess a vegetable garden looks better, is better taken care of, has [pride of place](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pride%20of%20place), etc. In contrast, a vegetable patch feels like just a practical place to grow vegetables without much care for how it looks.

THAT SAID, many people refer to their well-manicured vegetable gardens as a "vegetable patch" because it sounds more [down-to-earth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down-to-earth). Gardens are also much more photogenic, so almost everything that pops up on a Google Image search for "vegetable patch" will actually be a vegetable garden.